# Is transfer time included in the passengers transportation time?

Tags: openttd

If I transfer passengers from bus to train will it increase the waiting time or time spent with transportation? Maybe if I directly transfer passengers from city without transfer them with bus, I can get higher income?

Answer (score 1):

No, cargo waiting somewhere does never influence the income you can earn. However if too much goods/passangers are waiting at a station it will effect your station rating which effects how fast goods vanish. This will snowball towards local authority rating.

However when you are creating a detour on you feeder vehicles they can get negative income. This is [from the wiki](http://wiki.openttd.org/Negative_income_with_feeder_service):

> Now the train has the order to transfer at B. This time the train will have a positive income, however the road vehicles exhibit a negative income. Let's see how this happened.
>
> The payment for all delivered cargo no matter how it gets to its destination is done by a fixed rule (see for all the detail on the game mechanics page). Basically,
>
> - you get paid by the straight distance from source (the coal mine) to destination (the power plant)
> - you get fined for slower delivery from source to destination.
>
> The game does not know where coal loaded into the train is going. When the train arrives at station B and transfers the coal, the game makes an estimate of how much you should get paid. It finds that 732 English pound is a fair amount, and assigns that to the train as virtual money. Next, three road vehicles take the coal, and deliver it to the power plant at station C. Here, the game detects that the coal is being delivered to its final destination. It computes the exact payment (about 711 pound) for delivering the cargo from the coal mine directly to the power plant, deducts the already given 732 pounds, and comes up 21 pound short. As a result, each of the road vehicles has to pay 7 pound. In other words, the vehicles get the bill for the (apparently) overestimated payment of the train.